# Online Matchmaking Issues in Cloud Function and Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

A Cloud Function is set up to trigger when a new entry is created, and it checks whether we have enough players to start a game. If so, it creates the game at ‍‍`/matches` , and writes the `gameId` to each player's entry, like so: `/users/{playerId}/profile/cm`

Players listen to `gameId` on their own database entries, so they know when to transition to the GamePlay screen.

Since there are a lot of players request for find opponent simultaneously, and the Cloud Function is asynchronous concurrency , the concurrency issues come out and as you can see in the picture one user added in two diffect matches.

[image: Firebase realtime database image]
[image]

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.onNewRequest = functions.database.ref("/requests/{boardId}/{userId}").onCreate((change, context) => {
    var boardId = context.params.boardId;
    var createdUserId = context.params.boardId;
    // new request created
    var requests = admin.database().ref("/requests/"+boardId);
    requests.once("value").then((requestsSnapshot)=>{
        var waitersCount = requestsSnapshot.numChildren();
        if(waitersCount > 1){
            // more than one user waiting to join the game
            // lets link users
            var creatorSnapshot;
            var guestSnapshot;
            // more than two players waiting to play a game on the board{boardId}
            var index = 0;
            requestsSnapshot.forEach((childSnapshot) => {
                if (index === 0) creatorSnapshot = childSnapshot;    
                if (index === 1) guestSnapshot   = childSnapshot;
                index++;
            });

            // we have the creator and the guest
            // creatorSnapshot.key is the id of the user /requests/boardId/userId <<<<--
            var match = admin.database().ref("/matches").push({
                s: 1,
                peers:{
                    [creatorSnapshot.key]:true,
                    [guestSnapshot.key]:true
                }
            });
            match.then(()=>{
                // delete waiters

                admin.database().ref("/users/"+creatorSnapshot.key+"/profile/cm").set(match.key);
                admin.database().ref("/users/"+guestSnapshot.key+"/profile/cm").set(match.key);
                
                creatorSnapshot.ref.remove();
                guestSnapshot.ref.remove();

                return null;
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
            // var matchId = boardId + "-" + creatorSnapshot.key + "-" + guestSnapshot.key;
            // return admin.database().ref("/matches/"+matchId).set({
            //     s: 1,
            //     peers:{
            //         [creatorSnapshot.key]:true,
            //         [guestSnapshot.key]:true
            //     }
            // }).then(()=>{
            //     // delete waiters
            //     // creatorSnapshot.ref.remove();
            //     // guestSnapshot.ref.remove();
            //     return null;
            // }).catch((error) => {
            //     console.log(error);
            // });
        }
        return null;
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: This is issue of application logic. From database perspective it can be possible until you implement something different. Can you help me to understand which part of the code is preventing this issue?

Comment: I do not know, maybe my mind is deluded after more than 48 hours of not sleeping to solve this problem. Theoretically many way is possible but in code level is failed! e.g. Adding a pending status in the players that are currently being checked to match.